# Springboot 2 do not add any custom converter to Spring Data Rest (MVC part)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, converters

I use Spring Data Rest and I need add a custom converter. I have a workaround if I create a @RepositoryRestController with @GetMapping(value = "/search/findByFooId") ... I overide WebMVC part.

**1st converter:**

```
public class DateToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(final Date source) {
        return source == null ? null : ofInstant(source.toInstant(), systemDefault());
    }
}
```

**2nd converter:**

```
public class ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(final ZonedDateTime source) {
        return source == null ? null : Date.from(source.toInstant());
    }

}
```

**my Spring conf:**

```
@Configuration
public class MyRepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DateToZonedDateTimeConverter dateToZonedDateTimeConverter() {
        return new DateToZonedDateTimeConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter zonedDateTimeToDateConverter() {
        return new ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter();
    }

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRequestValidatorProxy companyRequestValidatorProxy;

    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        System.out.println("--- debug ---");
        conversionService.addConverter(dateToZonedDateTimeConverter());
        conversionService.addConverter(zonedDateTimeToDateConverter());
    }

    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(final RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Foo.class);
    }

}
```

**But I have this error:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.ZonedDateTime] to type [java.util.Date]
```